# A hemisphere rotating on a flat surface ends up on the flat side. Why?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation

So I was playing with my kid and this wooden half Kiwi (radius about 20 to 25 mm) got my attention:

[image]

What I noticed was, when I give it a spin on its pointy end and if a certain initial speed of rotation is exceeded, the hemisphere will always end up resting on its flat side:

[image]

I find this a bit intriguing because for the transition 1->2 to happen, the hemisphere's center of gravity must be lifted a bit. I assume that in some way or the other, rotational energy is converted to potential energy.

But why?

Comment: I wonder if a video of this would be helpful.

Comment: Thought so too, but it won't really stay in place when it's rotating. But I'll continue trying to make one.

Comment: Also does this object have a uniform density (as far as you can tell at least)?

Comment: I guess there may be some similarities with the [Tippe top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tippe_top)

Comment: I assume the density to be uniform, since it doesn't show a tendency to tip towards a specific side when at rest in position 1 (see drawing in the question).